# Azure Dev Ops - How do i override my Web.config with my securely stored Web.config (stored in azure Secure files) in a release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In our development environment, We store our connection string and application settings in the web config file. We have set up a simple CI-CD pipeline to deploy our app to azure app service. We have some dedicated settings only for our production environment but different in the development environment. the key is the same but only the value is different. Now I have stored the web config which is dedicated to the production environment in azure secure file. Now I just want to replace the Web.config with the secure Web.config to my App service (Production Environment).

It will be very appreciatable if anyone helps me to solve the issue.

Comment: If your application is in Azure, then the correct solution is to use keyvault and Azure app settings to override values in configuration files. There is no reason to rely on different versions of configuration files or transformed configuration files. Refer to the documentation on these subjects.

Comment: If you want to replace the file, you could download it from the repo in your CD pipeline and replace the values using a Powershell script for example. Or download the secure file and remove the original one.